# get count of employer from friend & friend's friend - facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know that using friends_work_history permission, we can access friend's work history. Now, I have 150 friends and out of these 150 friends, 45 friends authorized the app.

Because of this, I have work history of those 45 friends' friends.

Now, I need count of total unique employers of your friends AND your friends' friends who have authorized the facebook app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither FQL nor the Graph API has a `count` method. You'll need to take the results from your query and count these using another programming language.

Comment: ahh ok, can we get the list of employers of: 1) friends 2) friend of friend (who have authorized app)

Comment: You can get the list of employers of friends. You can't get access to friend of friends work data.